# libuv vs sockets in asp.net core 2.1

Tags: .net, sockets, asp.net-core, libuv, asp.net-core-2.1

As of ASP.NET Core 2.1.0-preview2 Microsoft has changed `libuv` to sockets.

Why haven't they used Sockets in the first place?

Is there a same implication of sockets in every operating system?

Is sockets are faster then libuv?

[this is the source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/04/12/asp-net-core-2-1-0-preview2-improvements-to-the-kestrel-http-server/)

Comment: .NET Core Sockets now utilizes Span<T> which makes it a lot faster than before. It now compares or even has better performance than libuv (in most typical cases). Remember libuv requires several dependencies which are now not needed. Sockets, as to my understanding, now works with IOCP similar to libuv, so there's basically no good reason to keep using libuv, other than very specific needs like listening to UNIX sockets.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why haven't they used Sockets in the first place?

Back then, sockets in .NET Core were too slow. That's way `libuv` was chosen. And maybe because `libuv` was "state of the art" at that point in time.

Later they decided to dogfood their own implementations (sorry I can't find the github-issue that points that out), hence sockets were improved and so it makes sense to use sockets instead of a native dependency like `libuv`.

> Is sockets are faster then libuv?

See [Announcing .NET Core 2.1 Preview 1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/02/27/announcing-net-core-2-1-preview-1) section "Sockets Performance and HTTP Managed Handler" for info.